# Did Rostropovich ever play his Humoresque himself?

Tags: history, classical-music

["Humoresque" op.5 for cello and piano](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoZgUeAFIKw) is the only piece composed by Mstislav Rostropovich himself.

Did he ever play Humoresque himself?
From some sources I know that he didn't, whereas other sources say he did and I'm looking for a credible information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a recording listed in Allmusic.com that lists Rostropovich as the composer and performer of his Humoresque for Cello and Piano, Op 5:

> feat. artist: Mstislav Rostropovich
>    Label: Brilliant
>    Rovi ID: MQ0000908851
>    Rovi Work ID: MC0002507948
>    AMG ID: F 1686750
>    AMG Work ID: C 380960
>    Work Title: Humoresque for cello & piano, Op. 5
>    Duration: 2:08
>    Recording Date: 1968-11-11

Link to page: http://www.allmusic.com/performance/humoresque-for-cello-piano-op-5-mq0000908851